# Android Lint complaining about activity not registered in AndroidManifest, but it is

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-activity, android-lint

When I run Android Lint on my project I get the following warning:

> The  org.slaytanic.SIMLockedRingNotifier.SIMLockedRingNotifierActivity is not registered in the manifest
>
> Issue: Ensures that Activities, Services and Content Providers are registered in the manifest
>
> Id: Registered
>
> Activities, services and content providers should be registered in the AndroidManifext.xml file using ,  and  tags.
>
> If your activity is simply a parent class intended to be subclassed by other "real" activities, make it an abstract class.
> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

**SIMLockedRingNotifierActivity.java**

```
package org.slaytanic.SIMLockedRingNotifier;

public class SIMLockedRingNotifierActivity extends Activity {
    [...]
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/application_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SIMLockedRingNotifierActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
[...]
```

I've also tried to replace the activity's *android:name* attribute with the full path`android:name="org.slaytanic.SIMLockedRingNotifier.SIMLockedRingNotifierActivity"` but I get the same warning. The app works perfectly and that activity is correctly added to the launcher. How can I get rid of it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sometime lint doesn't work well. i dont know why. but i escaped out from this problem by cleaning the project. and also there is setting for  android lint in window/preference(eclipse) where you can control lint to make it what to show as error or what to not.

Comment: RU using linux. it will work fine in Mac.

Comment: @PadmaKumar I'm running Eclipse 3.7.2 on OSX 10.7.4

Comment: @chrish I tried to clean the project but it keeps saying the activity is not declared.. I know I can simply ignore it, but I wanted to understand if there is a problem in my *AndroidManifest.xml* file.

Comment: Hm, if you only use lowercase characters for your java package name then? Using camel-case for packages is a *bit* non-standard, but Lint shouldn't be that stupid should it?

Comment: @Jens I made a big mistake using mixed-case for package name.. My app is already on the market, I think I can not change the package to lowercase without breaking something on google play, am I right? I'll ask another question.

Comment: @Jens I've opened a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869800/erroneously-used-mixed-case-package-name-on-an-already-deployed-app-can-i-chang) to address the possible problems related to a change of the package name to use only lowercase letters.

Comment: @GianniCostanzi - well, there's not much you can do about it in that case - package names are case sensitive & you cannot update the package name of your application without making it "a new one". Why not just [suppress](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings) the error since Lint is obviously a bit broken on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested with two quick apps in Eclipse and it does appear that Lint is unable to determine if an `Activity` that uses a "non-standard" package name with upper-case characters is correctly added to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The issue is logged in their [bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27529&can=1&q=Lint&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) already.