# Erroneously used mixed-case package-name on an already deployed App, can I change it to lowercase?

Tags: android, naming-conventions, package, google-play, android-lint

I have an app on Google Play whose java package name has the last part in *mixed-case*.. I was looking to remove an Android Lint warning (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868431/adroid-lint-complaining-about-activity-not-registered-in-androidmanifest-but-it)) and *Jens* made me notice that Java naming conventions say that you should use only lowercase letters for java package names, and maybe this is what causes the warning.. My app works correctly, but I'd like to change the package name to lowercase, to comply with java naming conventions.. If I change the name of the package to only-lowercase, will I break the correct behavior of Google Play? I.e., if I release a new version of the app with the new package name Android will not recognize it as the same app installed on devices and it will appear as a completely different app? Do you suggest me simply to ignore this mistake and remember to comply with naming conventions in my next project or could I have problems (worse than simple Lint warnings) with the mixed-case package name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Once you publish your application under its manifest package name,
>   this is the unique identity of the application forever more. Switching
>   to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that
>   can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.

Its not possible to change it . Please read http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html

Comment: Ok, let's hope my mistake will not break things in the future.. I knew it was one of the things that could not be changed, but maybe there was a work-around for my stupid mistake.. Thanks.